# Symfony 5 stripe v3 can't find CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID

Tags: symfony, stripe-payments

I'm trying to handle monthly  subscription with stripe :

I create a Payment Controller with actions :

create-checkout-session Action :

```
 /**
     * @Route ("/create-checkout-session", name="checkout")
     */
    public function checkout(Request $request)
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent());
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_...');
        try {
            $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
                'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
                'line_items' => [[
                    'price' => $data->priceId,
                    // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
                    'quantity' => 1,
                ]],
                'mode' => 'subscription',
                'success_url' => $this->generateUrl('success', ["session_id" => "{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}"], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL),
                'cancel_url' => $this->generateUrl('error', [], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL),
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return new JsonResponse(["error" => ['message' => $e->getMessage()]]);

        }
        return new JsonResponse(["sessionId" => $checkout_session['id']]);
    }
```

success Action :

```
  /**
     * @Route(
     *     "/{_locale}/success/{session_id}",
     *      name="success",
     *      defaults={"_locale"="en"},
     *      requirements={"_locale"="en|fr"}
     * )
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function success(Request $request): Response
    {

        $locale = $request->getLocale();

        // Get current user
        $user = $this->getUser();

        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_...');

        $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::retrieve($request->get('session_id'));
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($session->customer);

        return $this->render('payment/success.html.twig', [
            'current_language' => $locale,
            'user' => $user,
            'session' => $session,
            'customer' => $customer,
        ]);
    }
```

And i created a  script :

```
// Create an instance of the Stripe object with your publishable API key
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_..');

const createCheckoutSession = function (priceId) {
    return fetch("/create-checkout-session", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            priceId: priceId
        })
    }).then(function (result) {
        return result.json();
    });
};


$(".subscription-btn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let PRICE_ID = $(this).data('priceCode');
    console.log(PRICE_ID);
    createCheckoutSession(PRICE_ID).then(function (data) {
        // Call Stripe.js method to redirect to the new Checkout page
        stripe
            .redirectToCheckout({
                sessionId: data.sessionId
            })
            .then(function (result) {
                // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
                // error, you should display the localized error message to your
                // customer using `error.message`.
                if (result.error) {
                    alert(result.error.message);
                }
            })
    });
});
```

The payment work but i got this eror after redirect to success

[image]

> Invalid checkout.session id: {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}

[image]

How can i fix this error and how can i handle monthly payment inside my project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I just add :

```
$this->router->generate('my_confirm_route', ['myrouteparam' => $myRouteParam], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL).'?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}';
```

And in controller :

```
$request->query->get('session_id')
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the problem by simply decoding the url before sending it.

```php
urldecode($this->generateUrl('stripe-checkout-success', ['session' => '{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}'], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me (tested on Symfony 6) and in a Symfony context, I think this solution is more elagant than appending '?session_id' at the end (as mentioned in accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

Leroy is correct, but I'd suggest you confirm that the `success_url` you're generating actually looks the way it's supposed to - i.e. isn't having those {}s urlencoded - as that might be what's going on here.

Beyond that I believe your approach is correct, and Leroy's is not - I think you're not providing Stripe with an unencoded URL so it's not recognizing `{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}` as a template string as it should be.

Comment: thank you for you answer,  i'm using generateUrl to generate route with param and it doesn't work, i used a simple link  : 'success_url' => 'http://localhost/'.$locale.'/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',

Answer (score -2):

You pass that exact value to your PSP as success_url.

```php
'success_url' => $this->generateUrl('success', ["session_id" => "{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}"], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL),
```

Then you are getting back that redirect url, as literal : `/en/success/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`

Next you lookup that exact value `{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}` from some api.

```php
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::retrieve($request->get('session_id'));
```

I'm not sure, but I think you need to fetch the session id from the success_url's body instead of the the `$request` object.

I also think you can skip the session_id in the success_url, because that's the users's callback url. While the user is being redirected back to your application, the user is still logged in, You don't want to send your session id to your PSP.

I think your feedback is in the post body, based on what you've configured at stripe. Doing something like this should give you what you want.

First of all, remove the session id from the success_url

```php
'success_url' => $this->generateUrl('success', UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL),
```

Next, change your success url logic to use the post body.

```
/**
     * @Route(
     *     "/{_locale}/success",
     *      name="success",
     *      defaults={"_locale"="en"},
     *      requirements={"_locale"="en|fr"}
     * )
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function success(Request $request): Response
    {
        ...
        $body = $request->getContent();
        $feedback = json_decode($body, true);

        $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::retrieve($feedback['id']);
        ...
    }
```

PS, bare in mind that I haven't read the documentation about Stripe. But I strongly believe that they send you their session id (which you created) back in some form.